# Json_encode / JMS_Serializer, keep numeric key

Tags: arrays, json, jmsserializerbundle

I have a back-end API in symfony and front in vueJs,
In my app, I have a route for getting form definition ...

But for the entityType i need have the choice list so i do this:

```
$result['choice'] = array_reduce($config->getOption('choice_list')
                    ->getChoices(), function ($carry, $item) {
                        return array_merge($carry, [(string)$item->getId() => (string)$item]);
                    }, []);
```

In theory this return somethingth like :

```
[ "0" => "value1", "1" => "value2", "3" => "value3" ... ]
( note, key are not necessary continue)
```

In practice, debugger say "0" it's numeric so is int! 
And JMS or json_encode do the same ... and after serialization, I have a simple array without a key!

how can I trick JMS or native PHP function for getting a real associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result['choice'] = array_reduce($config->getOption('choice_list')
                    ->getChoices(), function ($carry, $item) {
                        return array_merge($carry, ["0{$item->getId()}" => (string)$item]);
                    }, []);
```

concat "0" front of the id do the trick :)

i have a "fake" string id in my form ... but when i submit the form ... symfony cast the "01" to int ^^